# Interpolation within single quotes

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation

How can I perform interpolation within single quotes?

I tried something like this but there are two problems.

```
string = 'text contains "#{search.query}"'
```

1. It doesn't work
2. I need the final string to have the dynamic content wrapped in double quotes like so:

   ```
   'text contains "candy"'
   ```

Probably seems strange but the [gem](https://github.com/datasift/datasift-ruby) that I'm working with requires this.

Comment: get search.query to return it's result wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: You never have to use single quotes - the created string doesn't know if it was created from a single quoted literal, double quoted literal, other literal or from other string operations

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `%{text contains "#{search.query}"}` if you don't want to escape the double quotes `"text contains \"#{search.query}\""`.

Answer (score 6):

```
'Hi, %{professor}, You have been invited for %{booking_type}. You may accept, reject or keep discussing more about this offer' % {professor: 'Mr. Ashaan', booking_type: 'Dinner'}
```

Comment: Just a note, `String.format` is preferable over `%` (according to Rubocop).  +1 good sir, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
%q(text contains "#{search.query}")
```

which means start the string with single quote. Or if you want to start with double quote use:

```
%Q(text contains '#{text}')
```