# How to make the say command echo a variable value in a script?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm on a Mac and sometimes I use the `say` command at the end of my scripts, like so:

```
system('say "Finished successfully"')
```

But if I try to insert a variable,

```
system('say "#{my_variable}"')
```

it doesn't work. It only echoes the variable name.

How can I come around this?

Comment: You can't do string interpolation within `''` only within `""` or `\`\`` (since you edited your post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove backticks ([Kernel#`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60)):

```
system("say \"#{my_variable}\"")
```

or

```
system("say '#{my_variable}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the system or remove the backticks:

```
a = "hello"
#=> "hello"
`say '#{a}'`
#=> ""
system("say '#{a}'")
#=> true
```

Since you edited your post to be single quotes instead of backticks, single quotes cannot support string interpolation, see [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912486/interpolation-within-single-quotes).

Comment: both say the word out loud for me.